# querying google fusion table

Tags: sql, select, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google fusion table with 3 row layouts as shown below:

[image]

We can query the fusion table as,

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=select * from *******************");
```

which select the data from the first row layout ie **Rows 1** by default. Is there any way that we can query the second or 3rd Row layout of a fusion table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API queries apply to the actual table data. The row layout tabs are just different views onto that data. You can get the actual query being executed for a tab with Tools > Publish; the HTML/JavaScript contains the FusionTablesLayer request.

I would recommend using the regular [Fusion Tables APi](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) rather than the gvizdata API because it's much more flexible and not limited to 500 response rows.

Comment: How to use regular Fusion Tables APi inside the above query code rather than the gvizdata API? ie, like the following `var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * from *************");` ???

Comment: @PradeepShankar, you can't.  It's a completely different API isn't compatible with the Query API.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for querying a Fusion Tables source has not been updated yet to account for the new structure, so this is just a guess.  Try appending `#rows:id=2` to the end of your table id:

```
select * from <table id>#rows:id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Querying Fusion Tables with SQL is [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-US&fromgroups=#!topic/fusion-tables-api-announce/_U1U4x2yD9g). Please see the [porting guide](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide).
2. Check out the [Working With Rows](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingRows) part of the documentation. I believe this has your answers.